# Seeking Free Task and Project Organization Software for R&D Work

Tags: project-management, time-management, task-management

**Hello community,**

I am an R&D professional in search of a free software or web application to efficiently organize my individual tasks and projects. While my team utilizes collaboration tools like Jira, I am specifically looking for a personal solution to manage tasks, research topics, personal projects, learning activities, and sometimes include detailed descriptions for future reference.

**Key Requirements**:

- **Individual Use**: I am not looking to share information with colleagues. The tool should focus on personal organization.
- **Task Management**: I need to organize tasks, assign specific dates, track progress over time, and include detailed descriptions for clarity.
- **Topic Grouping**: The ability to group tasks and projects by topics is crucial for my workflow.
- **Web and Ubuntu Compatibility**: The ideal solution should be accessible through a web browser and have compatibility with Ubuntu as a software application.

I've explored various articles on free applications, but many are trial versions or come with limitations. I'm reaching out to the community for recommendations based on personal experiences. Your insights will be highly valuable in helping me find the right tool for my needs.

**Thank you in advance for your suggestions!**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Asana. It is what I use.

- It syncs between Android and PC
- Single user is free
- You can use categories, priorities and dates or not or a mixture
- It has tasks and subtasks

Comment: Any link where to find it? ;)